# How can I have multiple API Gateway paths with GET requests in the awsm.json?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I'm trying to create an endpoint with many path parameters:

- /api/v1/{option1}
- /api/v1/{option1}/{option2}
- /api/v1/{option1}/{option2}/{option3}

Using JAWS awsm.json, I want to create GET methods for all 3 routes. How(if possible) can I accomplish this using Serverless Framework?
CF:

```
{
  "lambda": {
    "envVars": [],
    "deploy": true,
    "package": {
      "optimize": {
        "builder": "browserify",
        "minify": true,
        "ignore": [],
        "exclude": [
          "aws-sdk"
        ],
        "includePaths": []
      },
      "excludePatterns": []
    },
    "cloudFormation": {
      "Description": "",
      "Handler": "aws_modules/static/handler.handler",
      "MemorySize": 1024,
      "Runtime": "nodejs",
      "Timeout": 6
    }
  },
  "apiGateway": {
      ..path => /api/v1/{firstname}..
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

atm, there is no way to do this via Serverless Framework.

one thing i found out was that u can omit values in the url so itll be considered blank.

ex:

- api/v1/option1//option3

so this considers option2 as blank. so this kinda solves the issue except user would need to add the additional /s